# Print All Key and Value pairs without Quotations for Keys

Tags: python-3.x

I have this nested dictionary in Python:

```
data={
    "n": {
"identity": 25,
"labels": [
        "Transaction"
      ],
"properties": {
"date": 20141023,
"amount": 3890.36,
"currency": "USD",
"time": "6:09"
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to print out the keys and values for "properties" in a single line, but without the quotations for keys, like this:

```
date : 20141023 , amount : 3890.36, currency: "USD", time: "6:09"
```

So far, I can only print out the keys without the quotes (except for the final key), but not sure how to get the values printed as well:

```
for key,value in data.items():
    print("{}".format(":".join(value.get('n').get('properties'))))
```

Output:

```
date: amount: currency: time
```

Not really experienced with all this yet so I'd appreciate any help you guys could give me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
', '.join(['%s: %s' % item for item in data['n']['properties'].items()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(", ".join(["{}: {}".format(key,value) for key,value in data["n"]["properties"].items()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, Value in data.items():
    print(f"{key} : {Value}")
```